# Firebase iOS: Notification opened not displayed within console/analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-notifications

We are currently facing the issue that a click on a notification ("opened" within Firebase Analytics) is not shown app within the Firebase Notifications or Analytics Console.
We do see that notifications were sent, they do also received on the device, but the "opened" rate is always 0.

Unfortunately the integration guide for Swift has changed in the meanwhile (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift). We integrated it as follows:

```
onDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}

onDidRegisterForRemoveNotificationsWithDeviceToken(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0 ..< deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)
    Logger.info(self, message: "Device Token: \(tokenString)")
}
```

Does anybody has an idea? Usually there should be no TODO to have "Opened" tracked, correct?

Comment: It takes a day to get the values populated in the Firebase Console. Even the events which are logged will be available after 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, Google says up to 72 hours. But we have also notifications that are weeks ago, without any opened rate... so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Are you using the `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to send the notifications. According to the document it only captures for these.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-firebase-integrate-analytics/

Comment: I would wonder if this is the case. We are sending the notifications using the firebase console (web frontend) I guess in background they also use cloud messaging as API... but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue? I am also having the same problem, had no idea how it could be fixed.